# React Native display information on user scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm making a page in which we can add some filter and display some information with some filters ( ex: with brands, price, ...)

But when I delete a filter with a `<TouchableOpacity>` nothing changes in my page, but I don't understand why.

There is my code:

```
 const getProductsBySort = (
    itemId,
    check,
    brand,
    multiSliderValue,
    localOffset
  ) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(
        "GETPRODUCTBYSORT: ",
        itemId,
        check,
        brand,
        multiSliderValue,
        localOffset
      );
      dispatch(
        authAction.GetAllProducts(
          itemId,
          check,
          brand,
          multiSliderValue,
          localOffset
        )
      ).then((response) => {
        const updatedList = [...informationsBySort];
        let counter = informationsBySort.length;
        const newArray = response.array.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          key: counter++, // utilisez un compteur incrémental comme clé unique
        }));
        console.log("iciiii: ", newArray);
        if (newArray.length > 0) {
          setinformationsBySort([...updatedList, ...newArray]);
          setOffset(offset + 5);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
        resolve(newArray);
      });
    });
  };

  const loadMoreData2 = (itemId, sort, brandName, multiSliderValue) => {
    if (isLoading) {
      console.log("Je passe par ici");
      return; // empêche les appels multiples à la fonction de chargement de données
    }

    setLocalOffset(0);
    console.log(
      "loadMoreData2: ",
      itemId,
      sort,
      brandName,
      multiSliderValue,
      localOffset
    );
    setIsLoading(true);
    getProductsBySort(itemId, sort, brandName, multiSliderValue, localOffset)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          // mettez à jour votre liste de données avec les nouvelles données
          setinformationsBySort([...informationsBySort, ...response]);
          // mettez à jour l'offset
          setLocalOffset(localOffset + 5);
        } else {
          console.log("NO RESPONSE");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

 {listOfSort.length > 0 ? (
            <View style={{top: 11, marginLeft: 26}}>
              <View
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  height: "49%",
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  borderColor: "#ff7b0d",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  backgroundColor: "#ff7b0d",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    setListOfSort("");
                    setTrie(0);
                    {
                      brandName.length > 0
                        ? loadMoreData2(
                            itemId,
                            4,
                            brandName,
                            multiSliderValue
                          ) && setIsLoading(false)
                        : setCheckSort(false);
                    }
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={{color: "#fff", flex: 1, padding: 2}}>
                    Trie : {listOfSort} X
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
          {brandName.map((element, index) => (
            <View style={{flex: 1, width: "100%", right: "100%"}}>
              <View
                style={{
                  width: "90%",
                  height: "49%",
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  borderColor: "#ff7b0d",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  backgroundColor: "#ff7b0d",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  marginLeft: 40,
                  top: 10,
                  left: 20,
                }}
              >
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    brandName.splice(index, 1);
                    setCptValue(cptValue - 1);
                    let sort = trie;
                    sort = trie > 0 ? trie : 4;
                    if (brandName.length > 0) {
                      loadMoreData2(itemId, sort, brandName, multiSliderValue);
                      setIsLoading(false);
                    } else if (sort) {
                      loadMoreData2(itemId, sort + 4, [], multiSliderValue);
                      setIsLoading(false);

                      // getProductsBySort(itemId, sort + 4, [], multiSliderValue);
                    } else {
                      setCheckSort(false);
                    }
                  }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: "#fff",
                      flex: 1,
                      textAlignVertical: "center",
                      left: "20%",
                    }}
                  >
                    {element} X
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
```

And I display the information in a Flatlist:

```
<FlatList
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
  onEndReached={loadMoreData2}
  ListFooterComponent={isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : null}
  style={{top: "2%"}}
  data={informationsBySort}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <View style={styles.Products}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate("descriptionProduct", {
            data: item,
          })
        }
      >
        <View style={{width: "40%", height: "60%"}}>
          <Image
            style={styles.imageProduct}
            source={{uri: item.image_url}}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.productInfos}>
          <View style={{width: "60%", height: "30%"}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 15,
                bottom: "340%",
              }}
            >
              {item.titre}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              bottom: "1%",
            }}
          >
            <Text style={{color: "grey"}}>à partir de </Text>
            <Text style={styles.price}>{item.prix} €</Text>
            <Text style={{left: "50%", color: "grey"}}>
              {item.boutiqueCpt} offres
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

So if someone could explain me. I continue my research by my side.
Thanks you in advance guys.